# Avoid Nginx to add '/' before query parameters

Tags: vue.js, nginx, nuxt.js, nginx-config

I'm currently developing a Nuxt SPA that will be served with Nginx.

When I run de nuxt server localy, everything is working fine. But when runing the app on nginx, I have an issue when adding query parameters.

Actually nginx automatically rewrite all URL to add a trailing `/`. Thus, when add query parameter I am automatically redirected to: `www.exemple.com/my-path/?my-query-param=1234`.
But what I want is to access `www.exemple.com/my-path?my-query-param=1234` without the `/?`.

I tried adding `rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1;` to my nginx conf, unfortunately, this make me fall in a redirection loop (`?` -> `/?` -> `?` -> `/?` -> ...).

my current nginx conf is very basic:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.html;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
}
```

Can someone help me to fix my issue ?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

I also tried `try_files $uri $uri/index.html =404;` without any success :-(

Comment: You could try: `try_files $uri $uri/index.html =404;`

Comment: already tried this :-(